# Debian Gnome can't find Bluetooth headset

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, drivers, bluetooth

My Linux Debain OS with Gnome DE can not find the bluetooth headset but my android device finds it easily. although the Headset connects to Debian with 3.5mm jack.
Any solutions?

Headset: Koluman K6 - bluetooth version 4.1
Linux Debian 10
Gnome 3.30.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately i found the problem. it wasn't debian's nor Headset's problem. the headset needed to be in pairing mode to be found by other devices. after turning it off, then back on and holding the power button still, it goes to pairing mode and can be found.